# Number occcurencies in a vector

Tags: matlab, numbers

I ve got the following vector `A = [9 8 8 8 10 10 2 7 9 2]` and I want to calculate the occurancies of every number from 1-10. So I use the matlab's hist command:

```
occ = hist(A)
```

However I got as a result the following:

```
res = [2 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 2 2]
```

Why instead of having 2 in the second column of vector I got the two in the first column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you have to do it.

```
B=hist(A,1:10);
```

for example,

```
A =

     9     8     8     8    10    10     2     7     9     2
```

output after running the above command,

```
B =

     0     2     0     0     0     0     1     3     2     2
```

**Please go through the help of `hist` command for more information**

Answer (score 2):

The bin centers for the version of the `hist` function you are using are not where you think they are.  Try this and see:

```
[occ, bins] = hist(A)

bins = 
2.400000000000000
3.200000000000000
4.000000000000000
4.800000000000001
5.600000000000001
6.400000000000000
7.200000000000001
8.000000000000000
8.800000000000001
9.600000000000000
```

To achieve what you want, specify the bin centers manually:

```
occ = hist(A, 1:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the two-output form of hist reveals what's happening:

```
[occ, x] = hist(A)
```

This returns the positions of the bin centers in `x`:

```
x = [2.4 3.2 4.0 4.8 5.6 6.4 7.2 8.0 8.8 9.6]
```

[Naveen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24528506/2375855) explains how to set the bin centers manually.

Answer (score 1):

Because `hist` chooses the bin centers in a natural, data-oriented way, something like this:

```
MA = max(A);
mA = min(A);
offset = (MA-mA)/2/nBins;
binCenters = linspace(mA+offset, MA-offset, nBins);
```

with `nBins` the number of bins, which defaults to 10. Therefore, for the default call, you'll get bin centers

```
x = [2.4  3.2  4.0  4.8  5.6  6.4  7.2  8.0  8.8  9.6]
```

as shown by ojdo. To get the bins as you want, you'll have to use

```
B = hist(A, 1:10);
```

or

```
C = histc(A, [-inf (1:9)+0.5 +inf])
```

if you want do avoid this kind of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, which seems to be faster for large `A`:

```
res = sum(bsxfun(@eq, A(:), 1:10));
```